# Django-components - Include all js files of all components every time

Tags: javascript, python, django, components

I designed some components in Django using django-components library. I noticed when I use the `{% component_js_dependencies %}` tag in pages I use components, it loads all javascript files of every components. Is there a way to load only the javascript files of the components I use in the page ?

Thank you all

I tried to specify some option but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution<sup>1</sup>:

- Add `'django_components.middleware.ComponentDependencyMiddleware'` to your `MIDDLEWARE` section in the `settings.py` file.
- Add `'RENDER_DEPENDENCIES': True` to your `COMPONENTS` section in the `settings.py` file.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>[Here](https://github.com/EmilStenstrom/django-components/discussions/70) is the reference.</sup>